# Hector Visualization Cmake error

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I got this cmake error when building hector_visualization pacakge:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rqt_video_playback'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_visualization/rqt_video_playback)
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_PHONON_INCLUDE_DIR QT_PHONON_LIBRARY)
  (found version "4.8.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1171 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  hector_visualization/rqt_video_playback/CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)
```

Anybody got a solution to this one? Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214379/hector-visualization-cmake-error/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`hector_visualization` requires `Qt4` to be installed.
Seems you don't have this.

So install `Qt4`. I'm not sure which is included where, but I guess doing a `sudo apt-get install qt4-designer` will pull in all you need.
Probably you'll also need to `sudo apt-get install phonon` as [this seems to be required](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_visualization/blob/master/rqt_video_playback/CMakeLists.txt#L11) as well. But I currently have no machine to test this.

---

Duh, just tried it on a new install. Found the problem (hopefully).
You compile against `phonon`, so you obviously need the development library `libphonon-dev`, not just the runtime library... My bad for not checking this earlier.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-07-23**:
Hi there! Thanks for getting back! I have already installed qt4-designer and phonon (updated too). But this error still occurs.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-24**:
Can you please give some more information? Which OS/ROS-distro? Which branch from the hector_visualization package? Modified anything?

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-07-24**:
Thanks for the reply. I'm using Groovy and the package is a groovy devel branch. I didn't modify anything of the code inside. The problem seems to be due to the line 11 in CMakeList.txt (you linked that, thanks!). Maybe I have to edit so the packages from QT4 and Phonon can be found?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-24**:
Updated the answer above (even before you're reply ;-) ). You need to install `libphonon-dev`.

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-07-24**:
Wow! Thanks, I got it working already. You are a genius!